# Foaming wine. Rebottle? Or back to Carboy?

Tags: fruit-wine

My wine was fine. (This batch did stick and I added extra yeast) The last 2 bottles I opened foamed so much I lost 1/3 of bottle .  I have 10 bottles left. What should I do? Cool them ? Go back to Carboy?

Comment: did you stabilise and degas thoroughly before bottling?

Answer (score 1):

Chilling will not work.  Best thing might be to transfer back to a carboy and allow them to finish the fermentation, completely, before bottling again.  Give them a few more weeks.

Comment: I find that chilling prior to opening can make it less messy though. The colder it is the less fizzy.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to simply re-bottle right away but I see no good reason not to give it a few weeks.

If it is still fermenting I wonder if you neglected to add a stabiliser after fermentation?